# How to declare Doctrines Inheritance in a fixtures.yml file?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, yaml

I have a problem with the inheritance of Doctrine within my `fixtures.yml` file of Symfony.

Imagine the following:

```
NewsAuthor:
  inheritance:
    extends: sfGuardUser
    type:    simple
```

Now I want to declare the default guard user `User_admin` of the fixtures file of the [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) to be the author of the first dummy article of my News model. But how to do this?

I tried the following:

```
NewsAuthor:
  AuthorAdmin:
    sfGuardUser: User_admin
```

But then I get this error of the `doctrine:data-load` task:

```
Unknown record property / related component "sfguarduser" on "NewsAuthor"
```

I use Symfony 1.4.8 with Doctrine 1.2.3.

Thank you in anticipation,
Lemmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how Doctrine's inheritance works. Under simple inheritance, `NewsAuthor` wouldn't have a reference to `sfGuardUser`, it would have all of the columns and relations that `sfGuardUser` has plus the ones you define. Inheritance is a bad approach here.

Instead, you want a NewsAuthor to have a reference to sfGuardUser. Your schema in this case would look like:

```
NewsAuthor:
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
      unique: true #if one-to-one correspondence
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      foreignType: one
```

Your fixtures would then look as they did before:

```
NewsAuthor:
  AuthorAdmin:
    sfGuardUser: User_admin
```

You could then access the `sfGuardUser` object on a `NewsAuthor` object via `$newsAuthor->User`, similarly, you can access `NewsAuthor` on an `sfGuardUser` instance via `$user->NewsAuthor`.

Comment: Thank you for this well explained solution. But I don't understand what is Inheritance for?

Comment: It depends on the type of inheritance. I use concrete inheritance when I want to share methods across similar types that need to be in different tables. I use column_aggregation when the similar types will be retrieved concurrently.